# Can Google Wallet charge credit cards via Server Side code?

Tags: payment-gateway, payment-processing, android-pay

Can I charge credit cards via server side code -only- to Google Wallet (eg. via an HTTPS POST?)

If so :-

- Any links to this API?
- Can they accept transactions from $1 <-> $10 (ie micropayments).

So far, all I've read is that Google wallet requires both client and server side code :(

I don't want to use any client side code, but provide my own web page .. and that does all the charging.

(And no -> there's no way in hell that I'll be storing any POST'd credit cards, to my server, even though I will have access as I need to bounce that info forward to Google Wallet).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, [Google Commerce Payment APIs](https://developers.google.com/commerce/) leverage Google Wallet - stored payment info of Google users which you (merchant) will not really have access to (the *original* data) - otherwise Wallet sort of doesn't make much use for the (Google) user...

Here's a couple of FAQs on their [latest API](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/online/faq):

> **Q: What payment information does Google pass from the customer and the merchant during a transaction?**
>   A: Google will pass the following details associated with the one-time use debit prepaid card issued by The Bancorp Bank to the merchant: name, full credit card number, CVC, expiration date, billing address and phone number. Google will also send the e-mail address of the user and a shipping address if relevant. Google will also pass the last 4 digits of the customer’s real card to the merchant.
>
> **Q: What is a Virtual OneTime Card?**
>   A: For online purchases through merchants who have implemented the Google Wallet for online commerce API, Google Wallet will not share your full credit or debit card information with the seller. Instead, a Google Wallet Virtual OneTime Card (a prepaid debit card issued by the Bancorp Bank) will be generated and sent to the merchant to complete your purchase. Google Wallet will facilitate a payment using the Google Wallet Virtual OneTime Card and then charge your credit or debit card for the same amount.

AFAIK, this is also true for mobile wallet (phone/nfc).